# How to retrieve git clone "repo.git" 's downloaded data?

Tags: git, github, clone

Was cloning a big git repo (~1.2 GB) over an unstable network connection, though the repo download completed I couldn't see any of the loaded files, is there a way to retrieve the downloaded stack of files.

The output of Git Clone :

```
remote: Total 1648547 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1648545
Receiving objects: 100% (1648547/1648547), 1.21 GiB | 62.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1324539/1324539), done.
error: unable to write sha1 filename /home/amitesh/code_progs/python_progs/odoo/odoo/.git/objects/pack
pack-29584ab98800ae5d2d0a256f998e131416e350ec.pack: No such file or directory
fatal: cannot store pack file
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
error: unable to write sha1 filename  /home/amitesh/code_progs/python_progs/odoo/odoo/.git/objects/pack
pack-29584ab98800ae5d2d0a256f998e131416e350ec.pack: No such file or directory
fatal: cannot store pack file
fatal: index-pack failed
```

According above message, obviously, git clone failed. it seems you did not download data from remote. try git clone again please.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git fetch`, git should download needed files.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care of the history commit but just only the files, you can consider using `--depth` parameter, for example

```
git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

, to reduce the networking transmission about histories.